# Как вывести title из базы данных с помощью ajax?

Tags: ajax

Запарился с задачей с видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGjIEi-AaiM Тайминг:21:40
Нужно вывести title из базы данных
$query = $connect->query('SELECT `title` FROM `posts`');
и обновлять его с помощью ajax с title из формы, без перезагрузки страницы
мой код:

```
    <div style="display: flex;">
    
    <div class="from" style="margin-right: 200px;">
        <input type="text" name="title" class="title"> <br>
        <textarea name="content" class="content" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea> <br>
        <button type="button" class="button">Submit</button> <br>
    </div>

</div>




    <script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').on('click', function(){
            var titleValue = $('input.title').val();
            var contentValue = $('textarea.content').val();

            $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: "some.php",
              data: { title: titleValue, content: contentValue }
            })
              .done(function(  ) {
                  
              });
            $('input.title').val('');
            $('textarea.content').val('');

        })
    });

</script>




<?php 

require 'db.php';

$data = [
    "title" => $_POST['title'],
    "content" => $_POST['content']
];

$sql = 'INSERT INTO posts (title, content) VALUES (:title, :content)';
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute($data);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял это и есть файл `some.php`, возвращаем обычный json

```
<?php 

require 'db.php';

$data = [
    "title" => $_POST['title'],
    "content" => $_POST['content']
];

$sql = 'INSERT INTO posts (title, content) VALUES (:title, :content)';
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute($data);
return json_encode([
'title' => $_POST['title'],
'content' => $_POST['content']
]);
```

js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').on('click', function(){
            var titleValue = $('input.title').val();
            var contentValue = $('textarea.content').val();

            $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: "some.php",
              data: { title: titleValue, content: contentValue }
            })
              .done(function(data) {
                   $('input.title').val(data.title);
                   $('textarea.content').val(data.content);
              });
           

        })
    });
```

Comment: К сожалению, это не выводит title из базы данных. Но все равно спасибо